# SSIS execute package task - retry on failure on child package

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package which calls a number of execute package tasks which perform ETL operations

Is there a way to configure the Execute package tasks so that they retry a defined number of times (currently, on the failure of one of  the tasks in the child package, the execute package task fails. When this happens, I would like the task to be retried before giving up and failing the parent package)

One solution I know of is to set a flag for each package in the database, set it to a defined value on success and call each package in a for loop container till the flag is successful or the count exceeds a predefined retry count.

Is there a cleaner or more generic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, put `Execute Package Task` in a `For Loop Container`. Define a variable, which will do the count, one for a successrun indicator and a MAX_COUNT Constance. In properties of the Package Task - Expressions, define

```
FailPackageOnFailure - False
```

After Execute Task put a `Script Task` Read/Write Vars: `SuccessfulRun`, script:

```
Dts.Variables["SuccessfulRun"].Value = 1
```

In properties of the For Loop:

```
InitExpression - @Val_Counter = 0
EvalExpression - @Counter < @MAX_COUNT && @SuccessfulRun == 0
AssingExpression - @Val_Counter = @Val_Counter + 1
```

Connect PackageTask with ScriptTask using Success line.

OR

In `For Loop Container` define expression

```
MaximumErrorCount - Const_MAX_COUNT
```

But this one hasn't been tested by me yet...

Comment: What would be the condition to exit from the for loop if the 1st (or nth, N< max) run of child package succeeds?

Comment: Awesome, will use a slightly modified version of this method